# Why is time taken by O(NlogN) algorithm same as that of O(N^2)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, time-complexity

I wrote two functions `maxSubSum2` and `maxSubSum3`, both of which try to find the maximum continuous sum of a sub-sequence in a given sequence.

### `maxSubSum2()`

- Loops through the entire vector and sets a beginning marker `i` on each iteration.
- For each beginning marker `i` it sets a corresponding ending marker `j`.
- The elements bound between these two markers form a valid sub-sequence; therefore, it calculates its sum.
- And checks if it is greater than the previous highest sum.

```cpp
int maxSubSum2(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    int maxSum = 0;
    for(std::size_t begin = 0; begin < v.size(); ++begin)
    {
        int thisSum = 0;
        for(std::size_t end = begin; end < v.size(); ++end)
        {
            thisSum += v[end];
            if(thisSum > maxSum)
                maxSum = thisSum;
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

### `maxSubSum3()`

- Is itself a driver function to the recursive function `maxSumRec()`.
- `maxSumRec` uses divide-and-conquer to calculate the maximum sub-sequence sum.
- The maximum sub-sequence sum can be either in the entirety of the left part, or right part, or it can between the two (in which case, it is the sum of maximum sum in left part which **includes** its border: `center`, and the maximum sum in right part which also **includes** its border: `center + 1`.

```cpp
int maxSubSum3(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    return maxSumRec(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
}

int maxSumRec(const std::vector<int> &v, std::vector<int>::size_type left, std::vector<int>::size_type right)
{
    if(left == right)
        if(v[left] > 0)
            return v[left];
        else
            return 0;
    std::vector<int>::size_type center = (left + right) / 2;
    int maxLeftSum = maxSumRec(v, left, center);
    int maxRightSum = maxSumRec(v, center + 1, right);
    int maxLeftBorderSum = 0;
    int leftBorderSum = 0;
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type idx = center; idx < v.size(); --idx)
    {
        leftBorderSum += v[idx];
        if(leftBorderSum > maxLeftBorderSum)
            maxLeftBorderSum = leftBorderSum;
    }
    int maxRightBorderSum = 0;
    int rightBorderSum = 0;
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type idx = center + 1; idx <= right; ++idx)
    {
        rightBorderSum += v[idx];
        if(rightBorderSum > maxRightBorderSum)
            maxRightBorderSum = rightBorderSum;
    }
    return max3(maxLeftSum, maxRightSum, maxLeftBorderSum + maxRightBorderSum);
}

int max3(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    if(n1 >= n2 && n1 >= n3) return n1;
    if(n2 >= n1 && n2 >= n3) return n2;
    if(n3 >= n1 && n3 >= n2) return n3;
    return 0; // <--- Should never happen
}
```

Because `maxSubSum2()` has a double nested `for` loops, its time complexity needs to be **O(N)**, and because `maxSubSum3()` uses divide and conquer, its time complexity needs to be **O(NlogN)**.

However, I created a simple running time calculation function `stopwatch()` to measure the actual running time `runtime` for each function. It looks like the following:

```cpp
void stopwatch(int (*maxSubSumN)(const std::vector<int>&), const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    std::chrono::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    maxSubSumN(v);
    std::chrono::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> runtime = end - start;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << std::left << std::setw(9) << runtime.count();
}
```

Before the program begins, I populate two vectors `small` and `big` with 1000 and 10000 randomly generated `int` respectively; like this:

```cpp
int randInt()
{
    return std::rand() % 101 - 50;
}

void populate(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    for(int &i : v)
        i = randInt();
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    std::vector<int> small(1000);
    std::vector<int> big(10000);
    populate(small);
    populate(big);
    std::cout << "[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE] \t: ";
    stopwatch(maxSubSum2, small);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE] \t: ";
    stopwatch(maxSubSum2, big);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[DIVIDE AND CONQUER] \t\t: ";
    stopwatch(maxSubSum3, small);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[DIVIDE AND CONQUER] \t\t: ";
    stopwatch(maxSubSum3, big);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, after running the program several times, the execution time for both `maxSubSum2` and `maxSubSum3` is almost identical. Below are the results on my machine.

### `small.size() == 10 && big.size() == 100`

```
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.000001015
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.000041509
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.000001789
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.000058110
```

### `small.size() == 100 && big.size() == 1000`

```
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.000042093
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.003870208
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.000053203
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.003899243
```

### `small.size() == 1000 && big.size() == 10000`

```
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.002765456
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.271172096
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.002931273
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.274476880
```

### `small.size() == 1000 && big.size() == 1000000`

```
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 0.002730444
[OPTIMIZED BRUTE FORCE]         : 26.383375030
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 0.002903615
[DIVIDE AND CONQUER]            : 26.508168165
```

- Is there something that I did wrong in calculation of time complexities?
- Did I make some mistake in the implementation of `maxSumRec` *it gives the right results though*?
- Is there some other bottleneck in the implementation that I did not consider?
- Or, is there something that I am missing or did not understand?

Any help would be highly appreciated. For reference, I am learning from the book: [Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ (4th Edition)](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Weiss-Data-Structures-and-Algorithm-Analysis-in-C-4th-Edition/PGM148299.html).

### Problem solved. Problematic part: use of overflowing integer

See [interjay's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72904384/18311567)

```cpp
for(std::vector<int>::size_type idx = center; idx < v.size(); --idx)
```

> It makes a difference because the loop is only supposed to go down to left but you made it go down to 0. This changes the recursive call's runtime to O(n) instead of O(right - left), and the total runtime to O(n^2) because there are a total of O(n) recursive calls

**Credits:** [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay)

Comment: If anyone wants to test the program by running it on their machines; this is the [link to the complete program](https://pastebin.com/np18cPM2)

Comment: `10000` -- That is still a small amount.  Try a million, if not more than that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried it takes too long! But the results are still the same :(

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Let me edit the question to add the results for million

Comment: What takes too long?  If you're talking about the n^2 version, well, of course it does.  If you're talking about the one you are claiming is logarithmic, then that code has one or more bugs, since a million items would take a max of 20 "iterations".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It should, but as it currently is, it is taking 26 seconds ! Both of them :/

Comment: Then your program has bugs, or the running complexity isn't what you claim it is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is why I asked this question. I already pounded on it for some time, but could not find what am I doing wrong. Please read the second last paragraph of my question.

Comment: Remember that you're talking about theoretical asymptotic behaviour and completely ignoring the practical. Some times it takes the smarter algorithm a lot of data to finally outperform a stupid algorithm that the processor happens to favour thanks to predictability and easy caching.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks and it might be so!. I would really appreciate if could take a look over the program and see if you could find something interesting.

Comment: Have you compared the output of both algorithms to see if the recursive one is even producing the correct answer? That would tell you right away that there's a problem. The left sum loop seems to be incorrect in the recursive algorithm (going from center to the end rather than from left to center which would make more sense).

Comment: @Kyle As I said in the second last paragraph of my question. It does produce the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type idx = center; idx < v.size(); --idx)
```

This loop doesn't make sense. You're decreasing `idx` while `idx < v.size()`, which for an unsigned number is the same as decreasing it until it underflows past 0.  That will both increase your asymptotic runtime, and possibly give incorrect results.

You may have intended `idx >= left`, but that won't work for `left == 0` due to using unsigned types, so you may want to use `difference_type` instead of `size_type`.

In any case, I suggest making sure that both algorithms give the same results if you haven't done so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I will change the type and let you know if there is any improvement. For one thing I did already check and it does give the correct result.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I think (but am not sure) this bug doesn't happen to cause incorrect results because there's no harm in trying additional elements past `left`. But it will definitely hurt performance.

Comment: Do you want me to give you a kiss! It did solve my problem. I changed the loop header to this: `for(std::vector<int>::difference_type idx = center; idx > left; --idx)
`

Comment: The execution times are now correct! Thanks a lot.. Also can you please clear a few misconceptions.

Comment: I usually use revert to using `i < max_size` for `unsigned` types, because when the value decreases past 0, it wraps or overflows to `MAX_UNSIGNED_INT`, which is definitely greater than most `std::size_t`. Why would such a small change make such a huge difference?'

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen It makes a difference because the loop is only supposed to go down to `left` but you made it go down to 0. This changes the recursive call's runtime to O(n) instead of O(right - left), and the total runtime to O(n^2) because there are a total of O(n) recursive calls.

Comment: OHHH MYY GODDDDDDD ! YOU ARE SO CORRECT.. Thanks a lot brother. You do not know how much time I spent on this! Have a wonderful day. God bless you brother!